# how to log into a unix account with php

Tags: php, unix, authentication, account

I am trying to make UNIX account for the users on my website, but i don't know how to get php to make the accounts or log in. I have tried the shell_exec() command, but i don't know how to give it a password.
Thanks.

Comment: @webarto I always wondered how that expression was spelled... Wouldn't have guessed it ends with `q` :)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is certainly possible to coerce a server into allowing PHP via an HTTP request to create users, it is a security nightmare to setup and I highly recommend against it. You would need to defeat a number of security features built into modern Linux & Unix systems to make this work.

Instead I would probably handle this by running a frequent cron job that looks for new users in your database and creates a UNIX account for them via shell scripting.

The script would:

- Query your database for users created in the last few minutes
- Run `useradd` to create their accounts
- Run a password generation utility to set their passwords.

**Beware: There will be a lot of maintenance associated with this. Only undertake this if you are certain you understand the potential security and maintenance implications and you really trust your users.**

You may have lots and lots of unused shell accounts piling up. You would want a script that regularly cleans out/removes the unused ones. You would want to maintain a password expiry policy for the Unix accounts. You may want to lock down the access those shell accounts had to a subset of commands to prevent anyone registered on your website from using their shell accounts to turn your server into a spambot.  I could go on and on...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need ssh connection using php. But you have to be careful with permissions